# Customize eclipse-generated code

Tags: eclipse, code-generation, settings

I would like to customize the way, eclipse generates `hashCode` and `equals` methods. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beside the options you can see in the dialog during the generation, there is no easy way to customize the generated methods. You could however, build your own plugins that somehow substitute the default implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You want to customise the generator itself? I don't think it's possible. There are plenty of plugins which do the same thing however, which may be customisable.